# SOAP Web Services Attributes to verify authentication token

Tags: wcf, soap

I would like to create some sort of authentication attribute and attach it to various OperationContracts. Inside this attribute, it would check for an authentication token and make sure its still valid before the OperationContract is run.

What's the best way to implement this on the .net platform?  Does wcf have any special attributes that already do this type of functionality? What I'm picturing is something similar to the attributes you can attach to MVC controllers that will perform operations before actions are run.

In case it's relevant, I am using WCF to create SOAP web services that will be consumed by clients on various platforms that support SOAP.. not just WCF clients

Here's some code to clarify what I'm trying to do:

interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

[OperationContract]
string ValidateUser(string username, string password);

[OperationContract]
string GetDataAndAuthInCode(string authtoken);

[MyAuthorizationAttribute]
[OperationContract]
string GetDataAndAuthWithAttribute(string authtoken);
}
```

implementation:

```
public class Service : IService
{

public string ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    if (!Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
        throw new Exception("invalid user...");
    else
        return GenerateAuthToken(username);
}

public string GetDataAndAuthInCode(string authtoken)
{
    if (!IsAuthTokenValid(authtoken))
        throw new Exception("Auth token invalid expired");
    else
        return GetData();
}

public string GetDataAndAuthWithAttribute(string authtoken)
{
    return GetData();
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with ASMX.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what I'm looking for.. "Custom Behaviors":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S7